# Implement realm with data binding in android

Tags: android, mvvm, realm, android-databinding

I am trying to use Android's architecture component i.e.`data binding` with `Realm` database using MVVM pattern.

After exploring about the data binding and MVVM , i came across few approaches to bind model with the UI.

1. Declare Observable primitive fields in model and directly bind them to the android xml file.
2. Keep the model as it is with primitive data type and declare Observable fields in View model class

Now, as realm does not support Observable fields the option left is to use `Observable`

i have referred this article to use [realm with data binding](https://medium.com/@Zhuinden/realm-1-2-0-android-data-binding-1dc06822287f)  , but this article is pretty old one.

so my questions are

1. What is preferable while implementing data binding in android , bind model  directly to the android UI or declare obserable variables in view model and map them with the model ?
2. best practices to use realm with data binding

My question is pretty specific in context of realm and data binding hence its not a generalize question.

Answer (score 0):

I'll answer the first question only as I haven't used Realm for a while.

As you stated yourself, you cannot use Observable fields in the model that you use in Realm and you shouldn't ever do so. Model is to be kept simple. 
ViewModel is exactly where Observables belong. They should be bound to the view and only them.

Consider using the new LiveData classes instead of Observables and ViewModels from the new Architecture Components. They make things even easier and are now supported in Data Binding:

[LiveData Overview](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata)

[LiveData with Data Binding](https://android.jlelse.eu/android-architecture-components-livedata-with-data-binding-7bf85871bbd8)